# Correlation between variables of unequal size

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression

I am having two different data sets. First data-set is ratings given by experts for particular product (sample size of 200) and the second data-set is ratings given by users of that product (Sample size of 450). Now, I would like to know the inter-dependencies between user and expert ratings?

How can I check the same using SPSS? If someone know the answer, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have the situation that for some expert ratings, you have more than one user rating? And can you show what you tried, what worked and what not?

Comment: For the same product, users and experts gave their ratings after they started using that product. So there are different number of ratings (sample size) from experts and users at different time period. Now, I would like to know whether user ratings are influenced by the previous experts ratings and vice versa..

Comment: Do you know the chronological order of the ratings (eg. expert1, expert2, user1, expert3, user2 ...)?

Comment: Yeah. I have the data about time period when the expert and user have answered..

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking at one product, there is no reason to do a correlation. You don't have anything to link the expert reviews to the user reviews. (for instance, how would you do a scatter plot of experts on one axis and users on the other). Think about doing a simple t-test to test if the magnitudes of the two review types are not the same.

Comment: For the same product, users and experts gave their ratings after they started using that product. So there are different number of ratings (sample size) from experts and users at different time period. Now, I would like to know whether user ratings are influenced by the previous experts ratings and vice versa. How can i proceed?